# T is parameter type or class type?

Tags: java

I'm really sorry as I thought that I understand generic but I don't, shame on me.

What's the difference between these two

```
public static <T> void c(T obj) {
    System.out.println(obj.toString());
}
```

and

```
public static <T> void d(List<T> obj) {
    System.out.println(obj.toString());
}
```

As

```
List <Integer> l1 = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1,2,3});
Gen.c( l1);
Gen.d( l1);
```

Return the same output 
[1, 2, 3]

As `List<T>` obj behaves the same with `T` obj.

T indicates *parameter type* or *type of class/object* ?

Comment: Why would you expect them to behave differently?  In both case you're calling toString on a list.  In c you're calling it on an object of type T, which happens to be a list.  In d you're calling it on a list passed in as a List.

Comment: The problem with this example is that it does not actually require generics to work (You can simply make the parameter type `Object`), so it will be hard to see why they are different. Just try to pass something that is not a `List` to `d` though, that won't work, but it will work for `c`.

Comment: Hi, thanks, is there a way to tell me that the arguments themself are different?

Comment: c method will take ***something*** and printIt, the method d take a ***list of something***, and print it....

Comment: They're different but just doing the same thing right? I've just realized that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of `c`, your `T` can be anything, which includes a list.  But because Java doesn't know what it is, you can't do any list-specific operations on it.

In the case of `d`, your `T` has to be a list.  Because Java knows what it is, you can do things like adding and removing and iterating and so on.

Answer (score 1):

`<T>` is identical to `<T extends Object`. So `T` can be anything which extends from `Object`, which is every class in `Java`. You can, for example, write `<T extends Animal>`, then you can put everything in which extends from `Animal`, like a `Cat` or a `Dog`. The important thing is, inside the method you only know that it is some type of `Animal`. So you won't have `Cat` or `Dog` specific methods, even if you give the method an object of type `Dog`. You'll only have the methods of `Animal`.

In fact, this only restricts the view to the given object, like `casting`. See this example:

```
Dog dog = new Dog();
dog.bark(); // Works as it is a dog
Animal dogAsAnimal = (Animal) dog;
dogAsAnimal.bark(); // Does not compile, dogAsAnimal is restricted to Animal though it is a Dog
```

The same happens in your example. The method `c` accepts any `T` which extends from `Object`, so every object in `Java`. The method `d` accepts objects of type `List<T>`. These are `List` objects which only contain elements of type `T`. Again `T` means `T extends Object` in this case. So `d` accepts `List`s which contain `Object`s.

Okay, what is the benefit from generics? You can restrict objects to only work with a fix type `T`. The `T` can be arbitrary but it is fix, once choosen.
Take a look in Javas `List` class. Before generics, you could put anything inside a `List`, like `Cats` **and** `Dogs`. You would have to code a special `DogList implements List` class in order to only allow `Dogs` for `Lists`. Now you can code one `List` class and restrict it to one variable `T`. Take a look at this example:

```
List<Dog> dogList = new LinkedList<Dog>();
dogList.add(new Dog()); // Works fine
dogList.add(new Cat()); // Does not compile, Cat is no Dog
List<Animal> animalList = new LinkedList<Animal>();
animalList.add(new Dog()); // Works
animalList.add(new Cat()); // Also works
```

But we only used one coded class: `LinkedList`. There was no need to code different classes as `LinkedList` is generic and accepts `LinkedList<T>`.

Another example: We want to code an `AnimalList` but the user should have the possibility to restrict the `AnimalList` to a fix `Animal` like a `Dog`. So that he is able to use an `AnimalList` which does not accept `Cats`.
We do so by coding the class: `public class AnimalList<T extends Animal> extends LinkedList<T>`

```
// Only dogs can be added
AnimalList<Dog> dogList = new AnimalList<Dog>();

// Not possible as String does not extend from Animal
AnimalList<String> strangeList = new AnimalList<String>();
```

By the way, inside the class `AnimalList` our elements are from type `T`. As `T extends Animal`, such an object gives us access to every method from `Animal`. For example, the `AnimalList` could have a method like `isEveryoneAlive()`, it could look like this:

```
public boolean isEveryoneAlive() {
    for (T animal : getAllElements()) {
        if (!animal.isAlive()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

You see, the `animal` is of type `T`, which extends from `Animal`. Thus we have access to the method `Animal#isAlive`.